# How systemd timer work?

Tags: fedora, systemd, systemd-timer

I have `myscript.service` and I want this service to start every hour.
So I wrote `myscript.timer`

```
Description=My script timer

[Timer]
OnCalendar=hourly
;OnCalendar=*-*-* 0/2:00:00

[Install]
WantedBy=timers.target
```

I started `systemctl enable --now myscript.timer`, then `systemctl status myscript.timer`
And I got

```
[user@localhost ~]$ sudo systemctl status myscript.timer
● myscript.timer - My script timer
     Loaded: loaded (/etc/systemd/system/myscript.timer; enabled; vendor preset: disabled)
     Active: active (waiting) since Tue 2020-09-01 12:10:54 +05; 4s ago
    Trigger: Tue 2020-09-01 16:31:29 +05; 4h 20min left
   Triggers: ● myscript.service

Sep 01 12:10:54 localhost.localdomain systemd[1]: Started My script timer.
```

And I can't understand why it's not trigger in an hour?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Unfortunately, I'm not reproducing the issue you're seeing.  Judging by the commented `;OnCalendar=`, you've been changing the field.  Are you sure that you used `systemctl daemon-reload` between the edit and starting the timer?

When I test it out on my system I see:

```
$ systemctl --user cat mytime.timer
# /home/stew/.config/systemd/user/mytime.timer
[Unit]
Description=Test timer

[Timer]
OnCalendar=hourly


$ systemctl --user start mytime.timer
$ systemctl --user status mytime.timer
● mytime.timer - Test timer
     Loaded: loaded (/home/stew/.config/systemd/user/mytime.timer; static)
     Active: active (waiting) since Tue 2020-09-01 09:49:14 CEST; 7s ago
    Trigger: Tue 2020-09-01 10:00:00 CEST; 10min left
   Triggers: ● mytime.service

Sep 01 09:49:14 stewbian systemd[1691]: Started Test timer.
```

Then I waited 10m for the first timer to expire and got:

```
$ journalctl --user -u mytime.timer -u mytime.service
-- Logs begin at Mon 2020-07-06 04:41:08 CEST, end at Tue 2020-09-01 10:00:00 CEST. --
Sep 01 09:49:14 stewbian systemd[1691]: Started Test timer.
Sep 01 10:00:00 stewbian systemd[1691]: Starting mytime.service...
Sep 01 10:00:00 stewbian systemd[1691]: mytime.service: Succeeded.
Sep 01 10:00:00 stewbian systemd[1691]: Finished mytime.service.


$ systemctl --user status mytime.timer
● mytime.timer - Test timer
     Loaded: loaded (/home/stew/.config/systemd/user/mytime.timer; static)
     Active: active (waiting) since Tue 2020-09-01 09:49:14 CEST; 10min ago
    Trigger: Tue 2020-09-01 11:00:00 CEST; 59min left
   Triggers: ● mytime.service

Sep 01 09:49:14 stewbian systemd[1691]: Started Test timer.
```

In this case, I used `OnCalendar=hourly`.  The first trigger was at the start of the next hour.  The second trigger is set for the start of the following hour.

---

Since I suspect the issue is a `daemon-reload`, I tried to reproduce your problem by changing `OnCalendar=`.  I found:

1. If I use `systemctl daemon-reload` the change is applied
2. If I `systemctl stop` then `systemctl start`, the change is applied, even without a `daemon-reload`.
3. If I `systemctl start` without stopping the previous timer, the change is **not** applied and I get a warning about this:

```
$ systemctl --user start mytime.timer
Warning: The unit file, source configuration file or drop-ins of mytime.timer
  changed on disk. Run 'systemctl --user daemon-reload' to reload units.
```

Comment: I stopped the timer, just in case reloaded daemon and started timer again. But it doesn't work https://pastebin.com/K1Jvt6MR

Comment: That's a nice sterile log.  You're definitely doing everything right, I'm not sure why this problem is happening.

Comment: I have no words... It's triggered at 16:31:29 and then it works correctly

Comment: Great!  Fortunately the initial trigger is usually not so important when you are driving a timer on a machine that is always on.  But it's super annoying when we are testing.